# How many layout resource folders do i really need to cover all android devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, layout

I have found many questions and answers on this topic and have read through the developer guidelines but with many different device sizes out and no doubt more new sizes in future, what would be the best practice to cover all of these? i have seen people mention that by using layout-small layout-normal layout-large layout-xlarge, would be enough to cover the majority of devices that are out! i have seen others say not to use them as they are deprecated and instead should use layouts with smallest width i.e layout-sw380dp layout-sw480dp and so forth. with all this in mind i find my self mixing layouts and to be honest it gets confusing! take a look at this picture for example

[image]

I have many layouts, do i really need all of these? so to the experienced android developers i ask, how many and what layout resource folders do you use to target the huge range of devices out there?

Comment: "do i really need all of these?" -- probably not. "how many and what layout resource folders do you use to target the huge range of devices out there? " -- that would depend entirely on the UI of the app, and so we cannot answer that in the abstract. If your `minSdkVersion` is 14 or higher, though, you can skip the named sizes (e.g., `res/layout-large/`) and stick to the numeric ones (e.g., `res/layout-sw600dp/`). Even with an older `minSdkVersion`, you can probably skip them, as there were almost no Android 2.x tablets, and Android 3.x has not been relevant in years.

Comment: My minimum sdk is normally 14 and i did think about layout-large, was told that layout is for old tablets pre 3.2. 
then there is devices like the nexus 9 and nexus 10 to consider but found that layout-sw620dp and layout-sw700dp should cover these respectively

Comment: "was told that layout is for old tablets pre 3.2" -- and your `minSdkVersion` is higher than Android 3.2's 13 anyway. "found that layout-sw620dp and layout-sw700dp should cover these respectively" -- but you only need these directories if you have distinctly different layouts. Web developers do not create different versions of a Web site for every possible browser viewport size. Instead, they might have a dedicated mobile site and handle the rest via CSS rules. The same holds true with Android development, though the techniques differ.

Answer (score 1):

Usually i keep all auto-generated directories because with the "default" structure you can create application for many devices. If you want create an app that uses more graphical details, you should use all already created directory that are in the screenshot

EDIT:
Default structure = This is the auto-generated directories for new project with Android Studio :)

Comment: The auto generated structure is one folder with this just being called = layout! i don't think that is enough to cover the amount of screen sizes that are out there.